# Python ctypes call is mangling my pointer value in 64-bit mode

Tags: python, c, windows, ctypes

I have a C method I'm trying to call from Python

```
OVR_EXPORT void ovrHmd_EndEyeRender(ovrHmd hmd, ovrEyeType eye,
                                    ovrPosef renderPose, ovrTexture* eyeTexture)
```

On the python side it's declared like this:

```
for _lib in _libs.itervalues():
  if not hasattr(_lib, 'ovrHmd_EndEyeRender'):
    continue
  ovrHmd_EndEyeRender = _lib.ovrHmd_EndEyeRender
  ovrHmd_EndEyeRender.argtypes = [hmd, ovrEyeType, pose, POINTER(texture)]
  ovrHmd_EndEyeRender.restype = None
  break
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
ovrHmd_EndEyeRender(self.hmd, eye, p, pointer(t))
```

However, it's not having the desired effect.  In both Python and C I added some debug logging:

Python:

```
print 'address:', ctypes.addressof(t), type(t)
```

C:

```
OVR_DEBUG_LOG(("addressof texture: %d", eyeTexture));
```

In my console output I get different values:

```
address: 48163936 <class 'oculusvr.struct_ovrTexture_'>
Debug: addressof texture: 488341928
```

Other wrapped functions that pass values by pointer seem to be working OK though.  In addition, the problem only seems to be occurring in my Windows environment.  In Linux, the application works.

Anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Check all other arguments too.  Maybe the type of one of them is bogus, leading to CTypes and the C side expecting a different size, and then all arguments after it are shifted.

Comment: The four parameters are passed in registers RCX, RDX, R8, and R9. An implicit pointer is used when passing a value larger than 64-bit. There shouldn't be an alignment issue corrupting the pointer value.

Comment: @ArminRigo I've discovered that the code works in 32 bit environments, but not in 64 bit.  Also, I've looked at the values and sizes of the other parameters, and they all appear to be OK, so I don't think it's an issue with mismatched type sizes.

Comment: I think there are some issues on Win64 with ctypes on some versions of CPython, but it shouldn't be a problem here if all parameters fit into 64 bits...  Can you reduce the problem to a complete example that fails?